# Svcutil generating bad config with multiple endpoints

Tags: xml, wcf, soap, svcutil.exe

I have a WCF service that has exposed a soap and an xml endpoint.  When I use svcutil to generate the proxy code on the client side the generated configuration contains two endpoints which causes the client to fail.  If I edit the web.config file and remove the second endpoint (with the custom binding) all works as expected.  Is there a way I can get svcutil to generate a config that just works so that I don't need to hand edit the file everytime?

Client-side error:

> An endpoint configuration section for contract 'MyNamespace.ITestService' could not be loaded because more than one endpoint configuration for that contract was found. Please indicate the preferred endpoint configuration section by name.

Svcutil command:

```
svcutil http://api.local/Test.svc
    /reference:bin\MyNamespace.Interface.dll 
    /config:web.config 
    /mergeConfig 
    /out:"Service References\TestService.cs" 
    /n:*,MyNamespace
```

Generated client config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ITestService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
        <customBinding>
            <binding name="CustomBinding_ITestService">
                <textMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="64" maxWritePoolSize="16"
                    messageVersion="Soap12" writeEncoding="utf-8">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                </textMessageEncoding>
            </binding>
        </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://api2.local/Test.svc/soap" binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ITestService" contract="MyNamespace.ITestService"
            name="BasicHttpBinding_ITestService" />
        <endpoint binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="CustomBinding_ITestService"
            contract="MyNamespace.ITestService" name="CustomBinding_ITestService" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: What is in your service config file?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to specify the endpoint configuration name.  No way around it since they use the same contract.  This is why System.ServiceModel.ClientBase has that constructor argument.

```
var client = new TestClient("CustomBinding_ITestService");
```